# Why can't one physical adapter in a server connect to multiple virtual switches?

Tags: virtualization, network-adapter, windows-server-2012, switch

I am a beginner in all this, so please simplify the answer. I am just beginning to learn about hyper-v and virtualization.

Answer (score 1):

There wouldn't be a way for the system to know which virtual switch to send received traffic to if an adapter was connected to more than one vswitch so it would need to send traffic to all of the vswitches which essentially turns them into a single vswitch so there is no point in allowing such a configuration.